# Creating Json in Python without using "json" import

Tags: python, json, jython

I am running a function in Python to be used in Pig. Since Pig uses Jython to run Python, it does not have access to the json import.

I tried writing a dictionary and using that as json, but because it has ' instead of ", it's not valid Json. Any suggestions?

Comment: first suggestion is post your code. :). Let us see what you tried.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765305/portable-json-module-in-jython

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. 
While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, 
they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. 
A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, 
example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). 
The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: If you're really looking for a short-cut, go ahead and replace all the single quotes with double quotes. I've done that and had it work sufficiently for my purposes. But I had only very simple string values, no funny characters and such. I probably got lucky.

Comment: @davidvanbrink Same.  Works for most situations, but not all.

Comment: Why bother making your own? JSON is a really common technology, [this](http://aholzner.wordpress.com/2010/07/31/using-json-from-jython/) is just one of the many links that looks like it has a solution resulting from googling "jython json lib".

Answer (score 0):

This won't work in all situations; however, for most cases, you can use [replace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) to change out the quotes:

`output.replace("'", '"')`

Comment: I realize, @StevenRumbalski. It's not an all-inclusive answer.

Comment: The situation where it doesn't work is when one of the fields contains a double quote.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. Importing the json library was not a very good option because then I would depend on something that is not natively included in Pig nor Jython and I didn't want to manually copy jars to the grid.

I basically created the json manually, something like this:

```
def convert_to_json(name, is_on, section_ids):
sectionIdsValues = ""
i = 0
for id in section_ids:
    if i > 0:
        sectionIdsValues+=', '
    sectionIdsValues+=str(id)
    i+=1
jsonString = '{"name":"'+ str(bucket_name) +'", "is_on": ' + str(is_on) + ', "section_ids":['+ sectionIdsValues +']}'
return jsonString
```