# Python import Error: from .decoder import JSONDecoder: invalid syntax

Tags: python, json, python-2.6

I have a python module (getActiveLocation.py). It basically makes a http POST call, processes its response and returns it.

It makes use of json module. I am running python 2.6 on RedHat Linux. This module works fine when it is run standalone.
When the module getActiveLocation.py is run standalone, sys.path is

```
['/current_directory/','/usr/lib64/python26.zip','/usr/lib64/python2.6','/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk','/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages','/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages']
```

json module is existing within /usr/lib64/python2.6/ directory.

This python module (getActiveLocation.py) is imported inside a jython script (schedule_location.py) and when jython script is run, it is giving an import error for json module.

```
ImportError: no module named json
```

It looks like a sys.path issue.

I tried manually adding /usr/lib64/python2.6 to sys.path inside schedule_location.py via:

```
sys.path.append('/usr/lib64/python2.6')
```

Then the error changed to:

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 108
    from .decoder import JSONDecoder
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea why this error is happening? Your help is appreciated.

Vasily,

I am on a production system where I do not have any control! So upgrading jython is not an immediate solution for me :(.

I used simplejson as mentioned in the comment in [Portable json module in jython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765305/portable-json-module-in-jython)

But here again, it is working when I run it in python. But when run from jython, it gives:

`File "schedule_location.py", line 21, in ?`
`File "getActiveLocation.py", line 4, in ?`
`File "simplejson/__init__.py", line 113, in ?`
`File "simplejson/decoder.py", line 7`
`from .compat import fromhex, b, u, text_type, binary_type, PY3, unichr`
     `^`
`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

To overcome this, I used:

`from __future__ import absolute_import`

But it gave:

```
File "schedule_location.py", line 21, in ?
File "getActiveLocation.py", line 1
SyntaxError: future feature absolute_import is not defined
```

I understand that this requires python 2.5 or more. But I am on Python 2.6

Comment: What version of `jython` are you using?

Comment: Yoel,

I am not quite sure how to check the jython version. The JRE I have is version 1.6.0_24. So I suppose even the jython version will be the same.

Comment: What's the output of `jython --version`? Also, what's the output of `import sys; sys.version` when executed from within a `jython` script?

Comment: Yoel,

I do not execute jython directly. I don't have it in my PATH. So not able to get jython --version.

I call it as given below from a shell script:

out=`java -cp "$SYS_PATH" -Dpython.path=${SCRIPT_PATH}  weblogic.WLST -skipWLSModuleScanning -i ${SCRIPT_PATH}/schedule_location.py `

And an 

import sys; print sys.version 

gives me:

2.6.6 (r266:84292, Feb 22 2013, 00:00:18)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)]

Comment: Can you upgrade your `jython` version to one that has the built-in `json` module? I think it would be much simpler than forcing it to work with `cpython`'s `json` module.

Comment: @Yoel,

Just found out that the version of jython that I run (invoked by WLST scripting environment) is 2.2.1 which is way behind the latest one :(

Comment: Yeah, I figured it was not the recent version since it didn't have the `json` module built-in. That's why i asked whether you can upgrade it...

Comment: @Yoel: Sorry for the very late reply. Its a prod environment and so upgrade was not in my control :( . Finally I overcame my issue by using xml input instead of json for my POST call. It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

to make your code compatible with Python 3.x style imports.
Or try to remove "dot": `from decoder import JSONDecoder`. It should work in Python 2.6. Not sure about Jython.

EDIT: Found answer in the comment here: [Portable json module in jython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765305/portable-json-module-in-jython)

Comment: Thanks Vasily for the response. 

I tried import absolute_import. But it gives me:

SyntaxError: future feature absolute_import is not defined

And is it a good idea to remove "dot" from __init__.py which is part of a standard python file in JSON module?

Comment: Using standard module from other interpreter is not a good idea also. Using Jython with its own json module is better. I checked latest stable Jython 2.5.3 and it doesn't contain json module. But latest Jython 2.7 beta3 does! Check it out here: http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/python/jython-installer/2.7-b3/jython-installer-2.7-b3.jar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same SyntaxError when running a python script from a bash script. The solution was to specify the PYTHONPATH, e.g. PYTHONPATH = /usr/local/lib/python2.7. I also specified which python to use when running the python script, e.g. /usr/local/bin/python my_python_script.py.